# Could not find a part of the path 'AccessibilityManagerCompat_AccessibilityStateChangeListenerImplementor.class'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

while `build`ing xamarin forms android app in debug mode 
I am getting following error

`Unable to remove directory "obj\Debug\90\android\bin\classes". Could not find a part of the path 'AccessibilityManagerCompat_AccessibilityStateChangeListenerImplementor.class'.`

unable to find resolution for this as line number is not shown

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your path to the solution could be too long.  I solved this by moving my solution closer to the C drive root.  Also take into account that your application might not have sufficient rights to access that location, so make sure you give the necessary access rights.

Answer (score 13):

Manually delete your bin/obj folders from your Solution, and then try to rebuild.

Usually this does the trick, since it is trying to remove a class that he cannot find a path of.

Comment: This worked for me. Cleaning via VS was not working.

Answer (score 1):

Manually deleting the `obj\Debug\90` folder and subsequent build worked for me.

Clean and Rebuild didn't do it for me.

Comment: just re wrtting the above answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the path is short and **you dont have any spaces or special characters in the path to your project**

The latter one was the issue that haunted me for a while.

For example: C:/abc xyz/ProjectName/... is unacceptable because there is a space between abc and xyz.

I don't exactly know why but this works for me

Happy coding!

Comment: this helped me, although it's not right answer to question!
there are no spaces or special characters in above path.
thank you!